# ¿Cómo calcular la distancia entre dos coordenadas con la api de google en Angular?

Tags: angular, google-maps, objeto, gps, google-distancematrix-api

Necesito encontrar la distancia entre dos lugares. Tengo dos coordenadas, cada una de ellas recibe su lat y lng. Una de las rutas es fija, y la expreso de la siguiente forma:

```
let gps1 = new google.maps.LatLng(15.5039, -88.0139);
```

Pero para traer la segunda coordenada la obtengo de un objeto dinamicamente:

```
let lat = this.bookingService.bookingModel.loc = attentionSchedule.place.loc.coordinates[0]
let lng = this.bookingService.bookingModel.loc = attentionSchedule.place.loc.coordinates[1]
```

Y después solo "concateno" o "uno" la Lat y Lng creando una nueva coordenada con la lib de google algo asi:

```
let gps2 = new google.maps.LatLng(lng, lat)
```

Ahora que ya tengo `gps1` y `gps2` solo tendria que calcular la distancia entre ambas coordenas apoyandome de geometry de la lib de google para autocalcular

```
let distanceinMetro = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(gps1, gps2);
console.log('distancia', distanceinMetro);
```

Pero recibo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría obtener la distancia entre ambas coordenadas correctamente? ¿Es que acaso estoy recorriendo el objeto incorrectamente para obtener las coordenadas? Agradeceria mucho una sugerencia o una solución porfavor, gracias de antemano.

Dejo el objeto que estoy recorriendo y del cual obtengo las coordenadas de `gps2` https://github.com/IzliaB/json/blob/main/coordenadas%20json.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error indica que `geometry` no está definido, por lo que creo que no estás agregando la librería al cargar el api de google maps, este es un ejemplo de cómo agregar la librería

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry">
```

Comment: Si, eso era, gracias, no lei correctamente la documentacion. Gracias!